# didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called but not prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, audio-player, mpmediaitem

*This only happens when I've run the app fresh for the first time, and even then, when I try to recreate to debug, most of the time it works correctly.*

I select the song at the `indexPath.row`, and everything logs correctly, except the segue doesn't get called.

**It calls `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but doesn't call `prepareForSegue`.**

Everything is hooked up right, because if I try it again it works perfectly and both `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `prepareForSegue` get called. (I'm just using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for debugging to log that I'm not getting nil data.)

Has anyone run into this, or have any ideas of how to debug this?  Thanks!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        MPMediaItem *selectedItem = [[albumsArrayForTVC objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] representativeItem];
        NSString *albumDetailTitle = [selectedItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        MPMediaQuery *tempAlbumMPMediaQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
        MPMediaPropertyPredicate *albumPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: albumDetailTitle forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        [tempAlbumMPMediaQuery addFilterPredicate:albumPredicate];
        NSArray *albumTracksArray = [tempAlbumMPMediaQuery items];
        MPMediaItem *rowItemSong = [[albumTracksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] representativeItem];
        NSLog(@"track: %@", rowItemSong);
        NSString *song = [rowItemSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        NSLog(@"track name: %@", song);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nowPlaying"]){

        // send to now playing
        NSUInteger selectedSection = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] section];
        NSUInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];        
        NSArray *albumTracksArray = [self albumTracksForSegue:[[albumsArrayForTVC objectAtIndex:selectedSection] representativeItem]];
        MPMediaItem *rowItemSong = [[albumTracksArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] representativeItem];
        MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];
        [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:albumTracksArray]];
        [musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:rowItemSong];
        [musicPlayer play];
        NSLog(@"Row Item Song: %@", rowItemSong);
    }
}
```

[image]

*It's a weird one because its not something that I can recreate every time, thats why its extra hard for me to figure out what's going on here, whether it's something with the system music player or whether it's something in my code, etc.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. Note that both `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `prepareForSegue:` are methods of `UIViewController` and not of `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    //If you have only one segue then do just this else add your if condition for different segues 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: Should I be using both `prepareForSegue:` AND `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, or should I just be using one of the two of them?  If I'm still using `prepareForSegue:` do I still need to specify ` if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nowPlaying"]){`?

Comment: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//If you have only one segue then do just this else add your if condition for different segues
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];
}`

Comment: I see now on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.  Don't use `prepareForSegue:` then?

Comment: @SRMR You need to call `prepareForSegue:` within `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Just copy above comment in your code. Added in my answer, just copy that and put in your code.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense now.  If I only have one segue would it make sense to not use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or `prepareForSegue` at all?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, never link your segues using `UITableViewCell`. When you want to segue to another controller from your `UITableViewController`, link the segue using the controller. Control-drag for the yellow circle on the top of your controller to the controller you want to segue to and give it some identifier.

Secondly, in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, call the function `performSegueWithIdentifire` with your given identifier to segue to another controller.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: So what would be the case that you would ever link your segue using `UITableViewCell`? Would it only be if there was one segue/identifier? And then should I be using both `prepareForSegue:` AND `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, or should I just be using one of the two of them? And if I'm using `prepareForSegue:` should I not have the ` if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nowPlaying"]){` and instead put that part in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, or should that be in both?

Comment: Using `UITableViewCell` to link your segue is a bad practise. And you have to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for calling the segue. In your `prepareForSegue` you can check for the segue identifier using `if(segue.identifier == "your identifier")` and process accordingly.